# Will I brick a PWA if network fails on service worker cache update?

Tags: workbox

Let's say you during an update of PWA, the network cuts out and refreshing the cache fails. What state does that leave the app in? On refresh are some application files going to be updated while other are not? When a connection returns, will it try again? How often? How many times?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the service worker is implemented.

A common model, and one that I'd recommend, is to take care of adding to the cache during the `install` event, and take care of deleting from the cache during the `activate` event.

If the cache additions are wrapped inside of `event.waitUntil()` in an `install` event, and one of those additions throws an exception (due to a network failure, or some other issue) then the installation of the new (or updated) service worker will be considered a failure. The previous version of the service worker, if there was one, will continue to be used. The next time there's a navigation to a page under the service worker's scope, a fresh `install` event will be fired against the new service worker, and it will be given another chance to perform its cache additions.

If you only clean up caches in the `activate` event, then you don't have to worry about previously cached entries being deleted when installation fails, since the `activate` event will not be fired unless the `install` process was successful. (Your service worker might end up in a `waiting` state in between `install` and `activate` being fired, depending on whether there are other tabs open using the old version of the service worker, and whether or not you call `self.skipWaiting()`.)

There's a lot more information, sample code, and diagrams at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#updates